# eMachine ET1161 - Freeze and Crash

Tags: hard-drive, freeze, crash, emachines

I have an old eMachine ET1161 desktop back from the Windows Vista days that I'm trying to revive just for fun.

I wiped the HDD and installed a copy of Windows XP, it booted up and ran just fine for a short while until the screen mouse froze and the screen glitched out and I had to force shutdown. I tried a couple more times, same thing. Never runs for more than a few minutes without crashing. I dusted it out just encase, still crashed.

Booted up from UBCD on a USB and ran some tests, the HDD came back fine with HDAT2, the memtests came back fine, and the video stress tests as well. Wiped the drive again, installed Ubuntu, still froze up.

[This is the output when the error happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs7xu.jpg)

I know this is long winded and might not be fully clear, but I could use some help on this one. It obviously has to be hardware related but I can't think of what, the MOBO? The CPU? Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Either main memory corruption or a graphics card, or chip failure.

Comment: I did add two RAM sticks in to beef it up at one point, that could be a possibility. Any advice for diagnosing any of those thing?

Comment: Remove the ram upgrade, does it boot now?

Comment: So noticed a couple things: I removed the two extra sticks, started to get a boot failure. Tried moving the two RAM sticks to the purple RAM slots instead of the red ones, and then it booted correctly. Now I'm in and waiting for a crash. Also, one of the 4 sticks might have actually been the issue, it looks like 3 of them were HYMP125U64CP8-S6 AB and one of them was HYMP125U64CP8-S6 AB-C

Comment: Well, ran smooth for a while. Then it happened again http://imgur.com/a/YY4uz

Comment: All I can suggest it to put in a different video card in one of the open slots to test if it is a graphics issue.

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I get access to one, thanks for your help Moab